# Energy Manager error when reducing screen brightness during inactivity

Tags: lubuntu, 22.04, power-management, brightness, crash

Since installing Lubuntu 22.04 LTS the *LXQt Power Manager* has become unstable at some point. Going into your settings, in the settings section for "inactivity", I check the option "enable backlight change", in order to reduce the screen brightness after 1 minute of inactivity.

If I press the "Check Backlight" button, nothing happens, whereas in previous versions of Lubuntu it worked properly.

Upon completion of 1 minute of inactivity, instead of the screen brightness being reduced, the system displays the alert of multiple manager crash errors, resulting in its autorun being disabled.

Here is the screen print (with language in Portuguese):

[image]

I don't know about command outputs that are useful in this case. Here are the general descriptions of the system:

```
Chassis: laptop
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-43-generic
Architecture: x86-64
Hardware Vendor: Positivo Informatica SA
Hardware Model: Q232A
```

Thank you in advance for your considerations.

Comment: Seems to have been fixed on Lubuntu version 22.10 (Kinetic Kudu), it no longer crashes - at least on the live version of the USB stick.

Despite this, the LTS version still has the problem, and it would be good to solve it in this LTS version.

Comment: If it was related to the kernel (22.10 uses the 5.19 linux kernel), you may be able to use that in a few weeks [-edge, still 5.15](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/linux-generic-hwe-22.04-edge) though it won't be treated as *stable* until early next year. If it was related to LXQt version; a later version was available in [backports](https://lubuntu.me/jammy-backports-22-04-1/) but was recently updated [to LXQt 1.2](https://lubuntu.me/jammy-backports-22-04-1-lxqt-1-2/) that doesn't allow *release-upgrade* to 22.10 (*it contains newer Qt5 stack than 22.10 to allow LXQt 1.2 to run*)

Comment: Let's wait a while, maybe with this kernel update this will be fixed. Thanks for the information.